# Reading The Guide in light of Narayan's My Dateless Diary

Tags: r-k-narayan, the-guide, my-dateless-diary

R K Narayan's *My Dateless Diary* (1960) is a journal of sorts written during a long sojourn in the United States. Since this is his first visit to the US, Narayan often alludes to being shown the sights by tourist guides. Further, Narayan alludes at several points to a new novel he is working on. Here is a representative excerpt:

> Finished my lunch at four-thirty which is nearer the American dinner time, and hurried along to the National Broadcasting Corporation studios at the Rockefeller Center. An efficient guide took us along: he was witty, smart, familiar, and factual, as he took through room after room, and showed us with a good deal of explanation a few persons miming beyond a sheet-glass; and he pointed out elementary things such as boom, camera, monitor, etc. He behaved like a cheerful elementary school teacher taking his children through a museum. We were an assorted crowd: men, women and children, had converged here from the forty-eight states, and of course like me on their first visit. The guide's smartness, kindliness, elaborate speech, and ready wit, got on my nerves because it was so well-practised; his smooth speech, I suddenly realised, took the place of actual exhibits; after walking along endless corridors and up and down flights of steps, one realised that one had finally seen only charts and dummies and heard the guide's lectures on the technicalities of television. He reminded me of the chief character in my new novel,—a tourist guide who conjured history and archeology out of thin air.
>
> <sub>Narayan, R. K. *My Dateless Diary*. 1960. Delhi: Orient, 1969. p. 30.</sub>

*My Dateless Diary* ends within a couple of pages of Narayan's recording that he has sent off the completed typescript of *The Guide* (1958) to his publishers.

As this passage suggests, Narayan's own experience as a tourist connects to his portrait of Raju, the eponymous hero of *The Guide*. Additionally, on multiple occasions, the Americans Narayan encounters assume that since he is from India (and vegetarian to boot), he must be able to give them spiritual guidance. This too parallels *The Guide*, where Raju becomes a religious leader because his disciples see him as one.

It would seem, then, that the connection between the two works goes beyond their having been written at the same time. **How does *My Dateless Diary* illuminate the themes and concerns of *The Guide*? Have any scholars or critics explored Narayan's novel in the light of the journal he kept during its composition?**